# R gtrends time all missing

Tags: r, gtrendsr

I am getting missing date values when trying to download google searches using `gtrendsR` for `all` time periods.

```
library('gtrendsR')

g1 = gtrends(keyword = 'blues', geo = 'US', onlyInterest = T, time = "today+5-y")
head(g1$interest_over_time)

       date hits geo      time keyword gprop category
1 2014-06-22   21  US today+5-y   blues   web        0
2 2014-06-29   22  US today+5-y   blues   web        0
3 2014-07-06   21  US today+5-y   blues   web        0
4 2014-07-13   21  US today+5-y   blues   web        0
5 2014-07-20   21  US today+5-y   blues   web        0
6 2014-07-27   21  US today+5-y   blues   web        0

g2 = gtrends(keyword = 'blues', geo = 'US', onlyInterest = T, time = "all")
head(g2$interest_over_time)

  date hits geo time keyword gprop category
1 <NA>   36  US  all   blues   web        0
2 <NA>   36  US  all   blues   web        0
3 <NA>   37  US  all   blues   web        0
4 <NA>   38  US  all   blues   web        0
5 <NA>   36  US  all   blues   web        0
6 <NA>   41  US  all   blues   web        0
```

Any clues how to fix this?

Comment: Checking their github, try the dev version https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/310 (on the main github page)